# How to Create an HTML Editor with Custom UI in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, html-editor, flutter-textformfield, flutter-html, flutter-ui

I'm working on a project where I need to develop an HTML editor with a custom user interface using Flutter. I want users to be able to input HTML content and manipulate it using familiar formatting tools. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to implement this functionality efficiently. Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve this in Flutter? Any tips, code snippets, or recommended packages would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Reference Image:

[image]

i tried some package but all with static ui which not be customizable